# std::unordered_map<Foo, Bar> test if specific Foo key is present

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have an unordered map of Foo objects and I would like to efficiently test, if the key set contains of Foo objects with a given id.

One way would be to construct a Foo object and set it's id to the query value, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve this (maybe with a different data structure)?

```
class Foo {

    public: 
        int id;
};

namespace std
{
    template<> 
    struct hash<Foo> {
       std::size_t operator()(Foo const& f) const {
            return std::hash<int>()(f.id);
       }
    };

    template<>
    struct equal_to<Foo> {
        bool operator()(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) const {
            return lhs.id == rhs.id;
        }
    };
}


int main() {

  unordered_map<Foo, int> dict;

  Foo f;
  f.id = 123;

  dict[f] = 1;

  //How to test if Foo object with id x is present in dict? 

}
```

Comment: What is `x` in your question?

Comment: @ Kerrek SB It's 42

Comment: In C++14, use `std::map<Foo, int, std::less<>>` and do heterogeneous lookup (with the appropriate `operator<` defined) to avoid creating a temporary `Foo`. Also, don't specialize `equal_to`. Either write a `operator==` or define your own predicate type.

Comment: Another benefit of `std::map` over `std::unordered_map` is that an `operator<` is much easier to get right than a hash function. Unordered_map can degenerate to linear time, whereas there's a pretty solid logarithmic time guarantee for maps (though the typical red-black tree implementation isn't particularly cache-friendly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no more efficient way than creating a `Foo` object with the `id` that you want to test with this current collection. You are "stuck" using the key type that you chose in the first place.

If you want to index the dictionary by an `int` property, consider making that property the key and having the `Foo` object part of the value. (That could look like `unordered_map<int, pair<Foo, int>>` in this case.)